# Show homomorphism of semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

Given: $G=NH$ and $N\cap H=\{e\}$

Show the map $\alpha:H\rightarrow\text{Aut}(N)$, given by $\alpha(h)=\alpha_h$, where $\alpha_h(n)=hnh^{-1}$, is a homomorphism

Do I have to show $\alpha(h_1h_2)=\alpha(h_1)\alpha(h_2)$ for $h_1,h_2\in H$

or $\alpha_h(n_1n_2)=\alpha_h(n_1)\alpha_h(n_2)$

or both, but show homomorphism for the composition: $\alpha_{h_1\circ h_2}(n)=(\alpha_{h_1}\circ\alpha_{h_2})(n)$

I am a little confused as you are asked to show a map from a group to a group of maps is a homomorphism, but feel very close to understanding, any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to assume that $N$ is normal in $G$. To show that $\alpha$ is a homomrphism, you ned to show that $\alpha(h_1h_2) = \alpha(h_1)\alpha(h_2)$. You need to show that $\alpha_h(n_1n_2) = \alpha_h(n_1)\alpha_h(n_2)$ in order to prove that the image of $\alpha$ lies in ${\rm Aut}(N)$, which the question seems to be assuming, but it would be a good idea for you to show that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure that the map $\alpha:H\rightarrow\text{Aut}(N), h \mapsto \alpha_h$ is well defined, i.e. $\alpha_h$ is need an automorphism of $N$ for each $h \in H.$ For this you need to show that $\alpha_{h_1h_2} = \alpha_{h_1} \alpha_{h_2}, \forall h_1, h_2 \in H.$ Then you need to show that $\alpha:H\rightarrow\text{Aut}(N)$ is a group homomorphism, i.e. $\alpha(h_1h_2) = \alpha(h_1)\alpha(h_2), \forall h_1, h_2 \in H.$

Comment: I think it would be clearer for the well defined part to be applied to $n$. As $\alpha_{h_1h_2}(n)=(\alpha_{h_1}\circ\alpha_{h_2})(n)$, but I guess they are the same. Thanks for your answer